# Sanity building Error: Missing "./lib/exports" specifier in "sanity" package

Tags: next.js, sanity

i was working with sanity and everything was fine until today when i wanted to build sanity and i get this error : Error: Missing "./lib/exports" specifier in "sanity" package can someone help me? (i'm tried to upgrade, then i tried to downgrade the versions still same)

[image]

Comment: Hey, please copy and paste the text rather than pasting a picture. You'll get better responses that way.

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice if you could share some information regarding your project, like code, etc.

Assuming that you want to import `defineConfig`, Did you try to import it like this?

```js
import {defineConfig} from 'sanity'
```

For me, when building Sanity this works fine. Tried with Sanity Studio v3.7.0 and v3.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, after running a `git bisect` I discovered it was due to some weird conflict after installing some unrelated packages. I'm not sure what the issue was exactly, but removing `yarn.lock` and doing a reinstall fixed it for me.